# How to apply TypeConverter of type "Any" from Model Response from API?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using https://www.themealdb.com/api.php as my API.
Now, when I tried to generate a class from JSON, some fields are of type "Any".
How can I apply a TypeConverter for that?

This is the generated Data class of Meal:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "meals"
)
data class Meal(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int? = null,

    val dateModified: Any,
    val idMeal: String,
    val strArea: String,
    val strCategory: String,
    val strCreativeCommonsConfirmed: Any,
    val strDrinkAlternate: Any,
    val strImageSource: Any,
    val strIngredient1: String,
    val strIngredient10: String,
    val strIngredient11: String,
    val strIngredient12: String,
    val strIngredient13: String,
    val strIngredient14: String,
    val strIngredient15: String,
    val strIngredient16: String,
    val strIngredient17: String,
    val strIngredient18: String,
    val strIngredient19: String,
    val strIngredient2: String,
    val strIngredient20: String,
    val strIngredient3: String,
    val strIngredient4: String,
    val strIngredient5: String,
    val strIngredient6: String,
    val strIngredient7: String,
    val strIngredient8: String,
    val strIngredient9: String,
    val strInstructions: String,
    val strMeal: String,
    val strMealThumb: String,
    val strMeasure1: String,
    val strMeasure10: String,
    val strMeasure11: String,
    val strMeasure12: String,
    val strMeasure13: String,
    val strMeasure14: String,
    val strMeasure15: String,
    val strMeasure16: String,
    val strMeasure17: String,
    val strMeasure18: String,
    val strMeasure19: String,
    val strMeasure2: String,
    val strMeasure20: String,
    val strMeasure3: String,
    val strMeasure4: String,
    val strMeasure5: String,
    val strMeasure6: String,
    val strMeasure7: String,
    val strMeasure8: String,
    val strMeasure9: String,
    val strSource: String,
    val strTags: Any,
    val strYoutube: String
)
```

Unlike other API, example (NewsAPI) it generated a custom class of type Source and then from there, I can provide a converter easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is a superclass in `kotlin`, it means each class in `kotlin` has `Any` as a parent class

> open class Any (Common source) (Native source)
>
> The root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has Any as
> a superclass.
> https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/

If you are familiar with `Java`, it is almost the same what is `Object` in `Java`.

Usually autogenerators marks types as `Any` in `Kotlin` or `Object` in `Java` for fields where they have faced with issue to figure out the type. You could replace this fields by yourself

e.g.

```
val strImageSource: Any => val strImageSource: String
```

In case you still need a converter, lets say your date field you have received as a "24/01/2001", but want to save it as a long, you have to write the converter according to spec of your network library. In case you use Retrofit (a popular network/HTTP client), [here is a documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit) with details regarding custom converters

Comment: In this case, modifying the generated data class wont cause me any problem?

Comment: It should not. It is difficult to give more confident answer without more context including source code.

Comment: Its just a simple app. Regardless, your response is very much appreciated. Thank you